# Eclipse Formatter Issue: Annotation Type Element of Array Type

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, annotations, formatter

I have a problem formatting an annotation type element of an array type. I'd like to instruct the **Eclipse Formatter** to insert a space between the type and the name of the element.

So this would be great:

```
String[] value();
```

But all I get is this (no space between the closing square bracket and the element name):

```
String[]value();
```

Everything works fine if the type is not an array.

Probably I just do not know how to name the "annotation element type space after closing square bracket" correctly. Otherwise I suppose I would find the configuration option or at least a reference to a bug report.

Comment: Strange. Everything works for me with the default eclipse formatting policy.

Comment: @AlexR: Thanks for your hint!

I checked it with Mars Release (4.5.0), Build id: 20150621-1200 with both Eclipse configurations, but the result is the same: the space is removed.

Comment: I am using build  20130919-0819...

Comment: Ok, I remember not to have the problem on my older Eclipse installations. So it is probably a bug with the version I'm using ... Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome to open bug.

Comment: Reported: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478287

Comment: Good job. Hopefully the bug will be fixed in new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed with version 4.5.1

See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472962#c5